# Why is my gardenia covered with flies, ants, and other insects?

Tags: insects, bugs, gardenias

Why are insects of all kinds covering my gardenia?

Comment: Welcome to G&L. To help, we need more details please. A photo would be most helpful.

Comment: And some more info - like, where are you in the world, is the Gardenia indoors or outside...

Comment: Welcome from me too! As Patrick and Bamboo said, we need more info, especially because we can't see your plant.  If you post a picture, please get a close-up of these critters! Are they only on your gardenia, or your other plants too? Just the flower or also the leaves and soil? Is it in regular dirt or potting mix? Do the leaves look healthy? Have you checked out our [help], especially the [ask] page? You can [edit] new information right into your question. If you have trouble doing anything, leave us a note!

Comment: Waiting for your photos!!!  Please add your location, zone if you know it as well!

Comment: Does the picture in this question, http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/ants-and-white-gray-brown-spores-all-over-my-gardenia... look at all like your plant? Are any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely provide pictures...but Gardenias, Camellias, Jasmine with thick, evergreen leaves are beloved by aphids and then they poop a lot and leave 'honey dew' which attracts other insects and ants love aphids!  Do you have black gunk all over the leaves?  I'd wash my plant off with a hose or shower spray.  Look at the bottom of leaves especially.  If you have a hard time finding any insects it is probably *because the aphids are gone by this time of year (where are you?)*.  This may be all that is necessary until the spring which is when I would use NEEM.  At night to not affect bees and beneficial insects.  You might have to do a second application after a week or two if you are still seeing aphids.

Take pictures of the soil, the pot (if this is where it is planted), the stem and leaves; top as well as beneath the leaves.  Do you know what scale looks like?  This insect won't be bothered by water and scratching these guys off can break the epidermis of leaves/stems.  It would be FLAT, a slight bump, either dark colored or clearish and situated near the midstem of a leaf as well on stems.  If not, you don't have to do anything other than washing off the honey dew until next spring when you can use the NEEM.  If in a pot, drag the pot away to a spot where overspray can reach places you don't want to spray.  Don't spray in the wind and wear long sleeves/gloves.  NEEM is NATURAL but you don't want it on your skin or pets!  Please read instructions a few times before using...